# Why does this java 8 stream operation evaluate to Object instead of List<Object> or just List?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm working with a 3d party library, and they return Collections that lack type specifications  (e.g. `public List getFoo();`) , and I'm trying to convert their return types and return a list with a proper type.

I have created a simple example that demonstrates the problem. e.g.

*edit* The original question declared l2 as an `ArrayList` rather than a `List`, that is corrected now.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList l = new ArrayList();
        l.add(1);
        l.add(2);
        List<String> l2 = l.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

This fails to compile.

```
$ javac Foo.java
Foo.java:10: error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to List<String>
        List<String> l2 = l.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
                                                                  ^
1 error
```

If I modify the program slightly so it compiles and I can check the return type of the stream/collect operation. It "works", although I'd have to cast the result.

e.g.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList l = new ArrayList();
        l.add(1);
        l.add(2);
        Object l2 = l.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(l2.getClass());
    }
}
```

Running this shows...

```
$ javac Foo.java
Note: Foo.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
$ java Foo
class java.util.ArrayList
```

As expected.

So, Collectors.listCollector() does the right thing at runtime, but is this compile time behavior expected? If so, is there a "proper" way around it?

Comment: Do you know yourself the actual type the list is going to have? Does the library ensures that the list returned is a `List<Something>` but is returning for some reason `List`?

Comment: @Tunaki Yes. I think I'm just going to have to cast the object returned by the library to fool the compiler. I'm really curious though why, after the collect operation, it evaluates to Object instead of List or List<something>. Seems like there are way to many surprises in Java 8 streams.

Comment: You should tell the maintainer of the 3rd party library to get with the program. Java's generics were introduced 12 years ago. But I'm sure there's a long and sad tale that explains this.... :-)

Comment: @Bill One big problem here is that you're using _raw types_.  If you don't know what the `ArrayList` is a list of, use `ArrayList<?>`, not raw `ArrayList`.  The use of raw types is, in turn, making it harder for the compiler to give you the error message that would have made you say "doh, I get it" -- `toList()` returns a `List`, not an `ArrayList`.  (Also, the problem you had here has nothing whatsoever to do with streams, other than you happened to have used streams -- this is just not understanding the Java type system sufficiently.)

Comment: @BrianGoetz I agree completely that I need to understand the Java type system better! However the compiler still yaks if I declare `l2` as a `List`. The original example I gave was unclear, I have fixed it. The end result appears to decay into `Object`, at least as far as I can tell from the compiler message.

Comment: @Bill That's what happens when you pass raw types into a generic library -- things collapse to Object.  Raw types exist _solely_ to ease migration from pre-generic (1.4) to generic code.  That transition was 12 years ago.

Comment: @BrianGoetz I get it, and that's the purpose of the code I'm writing is to shield developers from this sort of thing in a third party library. If it wasn't a waste of my client's money I'd just rewrite the thing from scratch. ;-) Thanks for the help.

Comment: @BrianGoetz The transition to generics **started** 12 years ago, but it apparently continues to this day.... :-/

Comment: This question is now six years old, and it still gets upvotes. i.e. It's still useful to people. I'm kind of amazed, but I also find this interesting.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The `stream()`, `map()`, `collect()`, and all the other stream methods rely on generic typing for things to work well. If you use a raw type as input, then all the generics are erased, and everything turns into a raw type. For example, if you have a `List<String>`, calling the `stream()` method gives you an object of type `Stream<String>`.

But if you start out with a raw type `List`, then calling `stream()` gives you an object of the raw type `Stream` instead.

The `map()` method has this declaration:

```
    <R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)
```

but since it's called on a raw `Stream`, it's as if the declaration is

```
    Stream map(Function mapper)
```

so the result of calling `map()` is simply a `Stream`. The signature of `collect()` is filled with generics:

```
    <R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
                  BiConsumer<R,? super T> accumulator,
                  BiConsumer<R,R> combiner)
```

When called with a raw type, it gets erased to

```
    Object collect(Supplier supplier,
                   BiConsumer accumulator,
                   BiConsumer combiner)
```

so the return type of your stream pipeline is `Object` when its source is a raw type. Obviously this isn't compatible with `ArrayList<String>` and you get a compilation error.

To fix this, bring your types into the generic world as soon as possible. This will probably involve unchecked casts, and you should probably suppress the warning. Of course, do this only if you're sure the returned collection contains objects only of the expected type.

In addition, as [Hank D](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37215169/1441122) pointed out, the `toList()` collector returns a `List`, not an `ArrayList`. You can either assign the return value to a variable of type `List`, or you can use `toCollection()` to create an instance of `ArrayList` explicitly.

Here's the code with these modifications included:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ArrayList<Integer> l = (ArrayList<Integer>)getRawArrayList();
    l.add(1);
    l.add(2);
    ArrayList<String> l2 = l.stream()
                            .map(Object::toString)
                            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Answer (score 5):

Collectors.toList() returns a List, not an ArrayList. This will compile:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<?> l = getRawArrayList();
    List<String> l2 = l.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());

}
```

Comment: The library I'm using returns the undecorated type. So, unless I cast it, that decision is out of my hands.

Comment: @Bill, I updated the answer to assume a function that returns a raw `ArrayList`.  `ArrayList<?>` will accept an `ArrayList` without a cast.

Comment: Thanks, apparently, the compiler treats ArrayList and ArrayList<?> differently. I ended up casting the list to List<expectedtype> and it worked. I'm mostly curious about *why* it can't figure out that it's a list and decays into an Object. Not sure about what it is that I don't understand about the situation, and I'd like to fill that knowledge gap.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, after a couple of days distance from the question, I realized that mistake in the initial example. I have fixed it.