# Why stream.collect(toList()) returns Object?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

How, technically speaking, collect(toList()) can return Object?

```
Stream y = Stream.of("X");
Object l = y.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I would not be surprised by List, but Object that surprising.

Comment: Using the raw type `Stream` is the same as using its erasure, i.e. no generics at all.

Comment: possibly a duplicate => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214692/why-does-this-java-8-stream-operation-evaluate-to-object-instead-of-listobject

Answer (score -1):

It can return `List<String>` also, but it is normal to get an `Object` because `List` is extended from `Object`.

```
final List<String> x = Stream.of("X").collect(Collectors.toList());
```