# Why does flatmapping and collecting a list of treesets return an object?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to put all the values treeset elements of a list with treesets into a `linkedHashSet`. This list of treesets is returned by the `values()` method of a `TreeMap<String, TreeSet>`. The code looks like this:

```
Map<String, TreeSet> sortedByMonthAndVarietyNameMap = new HashMap<>();
    sortedByMonthAndVarietyNameMap.values().stream().flatMap(monthList -> monthList.stream()).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
```

This should be returning a `LinkedHashSet` with all the elements of the flatmapped treesets. But in reality it returns an object of type `Object`.

Why is this happening? Can someone explain what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this java 8 stream operation evaluate to Object instead of List<Object> or just List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214692/why-does-this-java-8-stream-operation-evaluate-to-object-instead-of-listobject)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TreeSet is not fully typed:

```
Map<String, TreeSet<Integer>> sortedByMonthAndVarietyNameMap = new HashMap<>();
LinkedHashSet<Integer> result = sortedByMonthAndVarietyNameMap.values().stream()
        .flatMap(monthList -> monthList.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have provided the constructor reference of LinkedHashSet without specifying the type.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you wish?

```
LinkedHashSet<TreeSet> collect = sortedByMonthAndVarietyNameMap
    .values()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(Stream::of)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
```

P.S. This data conversion looks strange. Perhaps you could describe your case in more details?

Comment: `stream::of` causes the returntype to become `LinkedHashSet<TreeSet<FavoriteResultDTO>>`!

Comment: my case is that i need the treeset. I am sorting by month because it is for a planting calendar. So the seeds need to be sorted by month, and inside the month list they need to be sorted by seed name, hence the treeset that automatically sorts according to `comparable` implementation.

Comment: `.flatMap(Stream::of)` does nothing (except wasting CPU cycles).