# Stream operation returns an Object instead of a List

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have the following code that executes as I intend:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class HelloWorld{

 public static void main(String []args){
    HelloWorld.TreeNode rootNode = new HelloWorld().new TreeNode<Integer>(4);
    List<Integer> traversal = rootNode.inorderTraversal();
    // Prints 4
    System.out.println(
        String.join(",",
            traversal
                .stream()
                .map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
        )
    );
 }

 class TreeNode<K extends Comparable<K>> {

     TreeNode<K> left;
     TreeNode<K> right;
     K val;

     TreeNode(K val, TreeNode<K> left, TreeNode<K> right) {
         this.val = val;
         this.left = left;
         this.right = right;
     }

     TreeNode(K val) {
         this(val, null, null);
     }

     List<K> inorderTraversal() {
         List<K> list = new ArrayList<>();
         list.add(this.val);
         return list;
     }

 }
}
```

However, if I replace the commented line with

```
System.out.println(
    String.join(",",
        rootNode.inorderTraversal()
            .stream()
            .map(Object::toString)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
    )
);
```

I get the following error:

```
HelloWorld.java:14: error: no suitable method found for join(String,Object)
        String.join(",",
              ^
method String.join(CharSequence,CharSequence...) is not applicable
  (varargs mismatch; Object cannot be converted to CharSequence)
method String.join(CharSequence,Iterable<? extends CharSequence>) is not 
applicable
  (argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to Iterable<? extends 
CharSequence>)
Note: HelloWorld.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

I saw this very similar issue ([Why does this java 8 stream operation evaluate to Object instead of List<Object> or just List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214692/why-does-this-java-8-stream-operation-evaluate-to-object-instead-of-listobject)), but I don't see how my solution doesn't circumvent the problem that user had because `rootNode.inorderTraversal()` return a `List<Integer>` instead of a `List`.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are using raw types. Parameterize it with the generic types like so.

```
HelloWorld.TreeNode<Integer> rootNode = new HelloWorld().new TreeNode<>(4);
```

This will fix the issue. If you don't supply a generic type parameter on the left-hand side, the List is declared as a raw type.