# Filter generic collection with lambda

Tags: java, generics, lambda

**Rephrased question at the end**

**--------------------------------------------**

I have to write two generic methods, to filter Collections of generic types.

First removeDuplicates and optional nulls from Collection< ? extends Object >.

Second removeDuplicates and optional empty/blank from Collection< String >.

```
private <T extends Collection<C>, C extends Object> T  removeDuplicatesFromCollection(T collection, boolean skipNull)
{
    if(collection == null)
    {
        return collection;
    }

    final HashSet<C> tmp = new HashSet<C>();

    for(C element : collection)
    {
        if(element == null && skipNull)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp.add(element);
        }
    }

    collection.clear();
    collection.addAll(tmp);

    return collection;
}
```

I did not know how to solve this otherwise. So i use a HashSet, to filter for unique, clear the origin collection and add all entries of hashset.

First i tried to solve this by streaming and using lambda expressions, but got also here  the problem here to handle with collect()

First i tried this by streaming and using lambda expressions, but did not g

it works, but I'm sure there must be a better way.

The first method is to remove duplicates and empty entries from Collection.
I ilke to filter this list again with lambda instructions and apache StringUtils, but I did not know how to deal with the collect and generic type T.

```
private <T extends Collection<String>> T removeDuplicationsFromStringCollection(T collection, boolean skipNull, boolean skipEmpty)
{
    if(collection == null)
    {
        return collection;
    }

    T removedDuplicates = removeDuplicatesFromCollection(collection, skipNull);

    if(removedDuplicates == null || !skipEmpty)
    {
        return removedDuplicates;
    }
    else
    {
        removedDuplicates.().filter(s -> StringUtils.isNotBlank(s)).collect(T::new); <== [X Cannot instantiate the type T ]
    }
}
```

Can anyone help to get this work?
If someone has a better solution for the first method, I would also be grateful, because I am not yet completely satisfied with it myself.

Many Thanks

------------[ EDIT ]----------------

I do not know the kind of collection from method input, put the output-type have to be of the input-type of collections.
HashSet => method => HashSet => return
ArrayList => method => ArrayList => return

I did not like to modify the input collection, but this was the only way i kept the type of collections.
Problem isn't the filtering the list during streaming, but the collect( )  at the end of stream, and creating an generic type depending on inputtype.
Problem is keeping type of input collection for output collection.

**--------------[ Rephrased  ]-----------------**

Let me rephrase and simplify the question, probably I shouldn't have written so much around what I want to do.
There were any useful hints and tips, but the core problem isn't solved

```
private <T extends Collection> T  doFilter(T pCollection, ....
{
    /** removed code for simplifing **/
    return pCollection.stream()
    /*.filter(....)*/
    .collect(  Collectors.toCollection( ?>>  T  <<?? ) );
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to collect(Collectors.toCollection(T)) in a lambda with a generic type?

So 
List<Car> => doFilter() => List<Car>
ArrayList<Person> => doFilter() => ArrayList<Person>
Set<Contact> => doFilter() => Set<Contact>
LinkedHashSet<Cat> => doFilter() => LinkedHashSet<Cat>

[T => doFilter() => T]
....

Comment: `C extends Object` is redundant, by the way. Everything extends Object.

Comment: You've right. I've took over this directly. Thank you.

Comment: But after this change, I did not have the C for the for-loop, so everything has to be an Object, and Hashset<> is instantiated with type obejct. but i will ensure the list contains an generic object. sure that can be object, but also class car or customer. Sure car and customer extends object, everything extends object, but so i have to cast everythin in object

Comment: Java 8 has the idea of "filtering" a collection, which is what you're trying to do. https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-applying-lambdas-to-java-collections/. It doesn't modify the original collection (which is a bad practice in general) and you just turn your collection into a stream, then apply a lambda that filters out what you don't want.

Comment: You can still have `C` but writing `C extends Object` is not specifying anything that `C` on its own does not.

Comment: sure i would be filter the list only by lambda, the problem is to return the generic type of collections with collect

Comment: This Item from Effective Java might help:
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2861454&seqNum=5

Its the first place I turn to when I have problems with generics

Comment: For your info, I say it is a bad practice because whoever gave your function the collection may not be expecting it to be modified, you are returning a collection (same collection? a new one?) and this kind of modification tends to lead to code that causes concurrency problems. It's usually better to avoid modifying your input arguments, unless you've got specific reasons to do so (low-memory embedded systems, large datasets for example)

Comment: i did not like to modify the input, but i did not know how to to other way. So i can return the generic type. Problem is to return a NEW Collection of gemeric type from input. So i put is a Set<Car> i get Set<Car> returned. If i put in an ArrayList<Car> so i will have an ArrayList<Car> for return.

Comment: After your rephrasal of the question, I must insist... You need to pass the type of the collection somehow. One way is by using a `Supplier` as I've shown in my answer. This means you have to change the signature of your method, but after my last edit, I've also shown a way to refactor your current methods to this new one. You can't do what you want without passing info about the concrete collection type as an argument. I've chosen to use a factory, another option is to use reflection and pass a `Class<T>` as an arg, but you cannot help passing info about the concrete collection type.

Answer (score 2):

Using the java 8 streaming API indeed leads to a cleaner implementation:

```
public <T extends Collection<Object> T removeDuplicatesFromCollectionAndFilterNull(T collection) {
  return collection.stream()
    .filter(Objects::isNull) // Method Reference to Objects.isNull(object)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet()); // Collect to set to remove duplicates
}
```

A similar approach can be used to solve the second problem. Be aware that the collect method does not take in a lambda to create the collection (and T::new wouldn't work as Java does not know wether the method has a default constructor), but a Collector. [This guide might help](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-collectors)

Comment: nice answer, but this did not recognize the optional filter for Null. Collectors.toSet is really nice, i will modify this by an filter (with the optional boolean flag)

Comment: Yes, you can use any Predicate to implement the filter, so customizing the filter implementation should be quite easy. e.g. .filter(obj -> skipBoolean ? false : Objects.isNull(obj))

Comment: got Type mismatch: cannot convert from Set<Object> to T

Comment: Yes, java erase the type of the elements in the collection in runtime. [This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214692/why-does-this-java-8-stream-operation-evaluate-to-object-instead-of-listobject) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use distinct() method on Stream

```
 Collection<String> list = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C");
   // Get collection without duplicate i.e. distinct only
    List<String> distinctElements = 
    list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will return all disctinct elements which are not null:

```
public <T extends Collection<Object>> T removeDuplicatesFromCollection(T collection) {
        return  collection.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        }
```

You can also use this example with Supplier:

```
  public static <T,U extends Collection<T>> U removeDuplicatesFromCollection(Iterable<T> iterable , Supplier<U> collectionType) {
        return  StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(),false).filter(Objects::nonNull).distinct().collect(Collectors.toCollection(collectionType));
    }
  List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("A","B",null,"B");
        removeDuplicatesFromCollection(strings, ArrayList::new).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: but i did not know, if the collection is a list, set or something. I have to return the genericInputType of the collection so the Imputtype matches outputtype

Comment: You can use Collectors.toCollection(Supplier<T> supplier)
I updated my sample in my answer you can checked it)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but we have some implementations the are already in use. i have to overhaul them.
we have some methods for input<List>, some for input<Set>, ....
these methods are all doing the same, and differnces only in type of collection. thats so ... 

i will merge all these methods to this generic method, so i can replace the old multipletimes duplicated stuff.

Comment: adding the Supplier, causes all methods in all implementations have to been modified, to add and use the new parameter

Comment: You can define in your interface default method with such realization and call it 
maybe it will not have such impact on code?

Comment: You can use  
public static <E> Collection<E> checkedCollection(Collection<E> c,
                                                      Class<E> type);
But you will need somehow to handle Class<E> type.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is to somehow know which specific type of collection you are dealing with, so you can create a new collection of this specific type and add the filtered values to it. It is bad practice to mutate your arguments, i.e. you shouldn't modify the received collection.

So I would use a `Supplier<T>` as a factory to create your specific collection:

```
private <T extends Collection<C>, C> T removeDuplicatesFromCollection(
        T collection, 
        boolean skipNull,
        Supplier<? extends T> factory) {

    if (collection == null) return null;

    // Remove duplicates, but keep insertion order (that's what LinkedHashSet is for)
    Set<C> noDuplicates = new LinkedHashSet<>(collection);

    // Remove nulls from the set if the flag is on
    if (skipNull) noDuplicates.removeIf(Objects::isNull);

    // Use the factory to create an empty instance of the collection 
    T newCollection = factory.get();

    // Add the no duplicates set, possibly without nulls
    newCollection.addAll(noDuplicates);

    return newCollection;
}
```

Now you can use the above method as follows:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, null, 5, 6, 1);

ArrayList<Integer> noDupsNoNulls = removeDuplicatesFromCollection(
        list,
        true,
        ArrayList::new); // [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```

---

**EDIT:** If you already have methods that do the same for every concrete collection type, i.e. one for `List<C>`, another one for `Set<C>`, etc, you wouldn't need to change all the invocations to those methods. All you'd need to do is change their *implementation*, so that they now point to the new method above.

For example, assuming you already have the following method:

```
private <C> HashSet<C> removeDuplicatesFromCollection(
        HashSet<C> collection, 
        boolean skipNull) {

    // .....

}
```

You could change it as follows:

```
private <C> HashSet<C> removeDuplicatesFromCollection(
        HashSet<C> collection, 
        boolean skipNull) {

    return removeDuplicatesFromCollection(collection, skipNull, HashSet::new);
}
```

And if you have i.e. another method for `ArrayList`:

```
private <C> ArrayList<C> removeDuplicatesFromCollection(
        ArrayList<C> collection, 
        boolean skipNull) {

    // .....

}
```

You could change it as follows:

```
private <C> ArrayList<C> removeDuplicatesFromCollection(
        ArrayList<C> collection, 
        boolean skipNull) {

    return removeDuplicatesFromCollection(collection, skipNull, ArrayList::new);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but we have some implementations the are already in use. i have to overhaul them. we have some methods for input<List>, some for input<Set>, .... these methods are all doing the same, and differnces only in type of collection. thats so ... i will merge all these methods to this generic method, so i can replace the old multipletimes duplicated stuff.
adding the Supplier, causes all methods in all implementations have to been modified, to add and use the new parameter